# Why is the throttle function in the code below not working?

Tags: javascript, html

The result is that when the page is just loaded, the image is not loaded. When the scrollbar is scrolled, the image starts to be lazyload, but the function throttle does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        img {
            display: block;
            width: 700px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <img data-src="./images/1.jpg.png" alt="">
    <img data-src="./images/2.jpg.png" alt="">
    <img data-src="./images/3.jpg.png" alt="">
    <img data-src="./images/4.jpg.png" alt="">
    <img data-src="./images/5.jpg.png" alt="">
    <img data-src="./images/6.jpg.png" alt="">

</body>

<script>
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

function lazyLoad(imgs) {
    console.log("oooo");
    var H = document.documentElement.clientHeight; //获取可视区域高度
    var S = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        if (H + S > imgs[i].offsetTop) {
            imgs[i].src = imgs[i].getAttribute('data-src');
        }
    }
}

 function throttle(fn, wait) {
    var timeoutID = null;
    return function() {
        if (!timeoutID) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
                fn();
                timeoutID = null;
            }, wait);
        }
    }
}


window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    throttle(lazyLoad(imgs), 2000)
});
```

The result is that when the page is just loaded, the image is not loaded. When the scrollbar is scrolled, the image starts to be lazyload, but the function throttle does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because throttle is a function that returns a function - a throttled function. In your case you run throttle whenever the event is called, and you call `lazyLoad(img)` inside it, which invokes `lazyLoad` immediately, and throttle is not doing anything.

To fix you should run throttle on the `lazyLoad` function itself, and set the the return function as the event handler.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

function lazyLoad() { // img is a global variable, so you don't need it as a parameter
  console.log("oooo");
  var H = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var S = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (H + S > imgs[i].offsetTop) {
      imgs[i].src = imgs[i].getAttribute('data-src');
    }
  }
}

function throttle(fn, wait) {
  var timeoutID = null;
  return function() {
    if (!timeoutID) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        fn();
        timeoutID = null;
      }, wait);
    }
  }
}


window.addEventListener("scroll", throttle(lazyLoad, 2000)); // use the throttled function as event handler
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?1" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?2" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?3" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?4" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?5" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?6" alt="">
```

If you wish to pass the event handler some parameters, you can use [currying](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339) -

```
function lazyLoad(imgs) {
  return function() {
```

The function gets the `imgs` and returns a function. The returned function can access `imgs` because they exist in the same closure.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

function lazyLoad(imgs) {
  return function() {
    console.log("oooo");
    var H = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var S = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
      if (H + S > imgs[i].offsetTop) {
        imgs[i].src = imgs[i].getAttribute('data-src');
      }
    }
  }
}

function throttle(fn, wait) {
  var timeoutID = null;
  return function() {
    if (!timeoutID) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        fn();
        timeoutID = null;
      }, wait);
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", throttle(lazyLoad(imgs), 2000)); // use the throttled function as event handler
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?1" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?2" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?3" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?4" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?5" alt="">
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?6" alt="">
```

Comment: thank you so much! Does it mean that if a function acts as an event handler, it cannot pass arguments to this function? If so, what is the reason for not passing the parameters? What should I do if I have to pass arguments to the event handler?

Comment: You're welcome. You can't call the function with the parameters, because then it will return a result. To pass parameters to an event handler it can be defined in the same scope (the parameter is defined were the function is defined) like in your case. Another option is using an object and referring to the parameter using `this` (requires binding). You can also use currying - I'll add an example.

Comment: thanks very much. your answers is very helpful for me. I am a newbie in programming from china . I just studied front-end development for six months. in college i learned little coputer science .by now after learning more than six months i still  feel it is hard . i plan to be a fullstack engineer in 3 years.can you share some  experiences in coding? for example how you learn the basic concepts in javascript such as these concepts below: function  event handler object and so on. i really apppreciate your response .

Comment: Just continue learning, practicing, and playing around. I've learned a lot from answering questions in stackoverflow, lots of tutorials (egghead.io, www.udacity.com/), books ([exploring es6](https://exploringjs.com/es6/index.html), Javascript The Good Parts, [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)). Lately I've recommended [freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/) to newbies. Good luck :)